# MySQL LEFT JOIN example

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP file and MySQL.

On a file, I need to select records from three tables.

If a make a query with two tables:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "
  SELECT * FROM tbgastos
  LEFT JOIN tbconceptosgastos
    ON tbgastos.tipoGasto = tbconceptosgastos.idConceptoGasto
  LEFT JOIN tbobras
    ON tbgastos.obra = tbobras.idObra
  ORDER BY fecha DESC
";
```

it works fine, but if I try to make it with three tables:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "
  SELECT * FROM tbgastos
  LEFT JOIN tbconceptosgastos
    ON tbgastos.tipoGasto = tbconceptosgastos.idConceptoGasto
  LEFT JOIN tbobras
    ON tbgastos.obra = tbobras.idObra
  LEFT JOIN tbproveedores
    ON tbgastos.proveedor = tbproveedores.nombreProveedor
  ORDER BY fecha DESC
";
```

the third table (`tbproveedores`) records are not shown.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATED

tbgastos

[image]
[image]

tbproveedores

[image]
[image]

Comment: What isn't shown, the columns?  Never use `SELECT *` in a join query. Specify the columns you need with aliases, as those having common names (like `id` are impossible to retrieve by name rather than numeric index.

Comment: need to see your table format and the relatonship.

Comment: Please supply your db-schema and some example rows. It's impossible otherwise to tell what's going on.

Comment: Or maybe you don't have any record related to your "proveedor" in your third table, you're making a LEFT JOIN here, not a JOIN.

Comment: @samitha, i have updated my question with table format and row content

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, i have updated my question with table format and row content

Comment: @NeeL, i have updated my question with table format and row content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your table tbgastos, you have a foreign key of a int type (proveedor).
And you want it to match to the table tbproveedores. Don't you want to point on tbproveedores.idProveedor ?

```
$query_Recordset1 = "
  SELECT * FROM tbgastos
  LEFT JOIN tbconceptosgastos
   ON tbgastos.tipoGasto = tbconceptosgastos.idConceptoGasto
 LEFT JOIN tbobras
   ON tbgastos.obra = tbobras.idObra
 LEFT JOIN tbproveedores
  ON tbgastos.proveedor = tbproveedores.idProveedor
 ORDER BY fecha DESC
";
```