# MySQL - Not Unique Table/Alias

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables, users, car and rent. 
rent table contains like transaction information. I want to display the output where some of users table column, some car column join with rent table.

I use PHPMyAdmin to extract the queries but I've got the "Not Unique Table/Alias" error.

My Queries:

```
SELECT `rent`.*, `cars`.`car_id`, `cars`.`car_name`, `users`.`user_id`,
    `users`.`name`, `users`.`state`, `users`.`address`, `users`.`zip`,
    `users`.`phone`, `users`.`email`
FROM `rent` , `cars` , `users`
LEFT JOIN `rent` ON `users`.`user_id` = `rent`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `rent` ON `cars`.`car_id` = `rent`.`car_id`  
AND `rent`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`  AND `rent`.`car_id` = `cars`.`car_id`
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary for the query to `JOIN rent` table twice? I suspect one of them might have to be `cars`? If you anyway still want the same table to be joined twice, you should use an alias: `LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1` and then for any of its fields: `t1.field1`.

Comment: Also, the `JOIN` has been used incorrectly - `FROM rent , cars , users LEFT JOIN...`. This doesn't help. Please have a look at this: [MySQL LEFT JOIN example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22769989/2298301)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT r.*, c.car_id, c.car_name, u.user_id, u.name, u.state, u.address, u.zip, u.phone, u.email
FROM users u JOIN
     rent r
     ON u.user_id = r.user_id JOIN
     cars c
     ON c.car_id = r.car_id;
```

Notice the use of table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.

I also have no idea why you are using `LEFT JOIN`, so I changed them to inner joins.

Comment: Thanks for your guide! I've been working on it for quite some time.. really thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The not-unique table alias means that more then 1 table has the same alias.

Your query:

```
SELECT rent.*, cars.car_id, cars.car_name, users.user_id, users.name, users.state, users.address, users.zip, users.phone, users.email 
FROM rent , cars , users 
LEFT JOIN rent ON users.user_id = rent.user_id 
LEFT JOIN rent ON cars.car_id = rent.car_id AND rent.user_id = users.user_id AND rent.car_id = cars.car_id
```

Should read

```
SELECT rent.*, cars.car_id, cars.car_name, users.user_id, users.name, users.state, users.address, users.zip, users.phone, users.email 
FROM rent , cars , users 
LEFT JOIN rent AS rent_1 ON users.user_id = rent_1.user_id 
LEFT JOIN rent AS rent_2 ON cars.car_id = rent_2.car_id AND rent_2.user_id = users.user_id AND rent_2.car_id = cars.car_id
```

to avoid this issue.

For the rest: The query looks to be a bit more elaborate then it should:
It looks like you can run it like this and get the same result:

```
SELECT rent.*, cars.car_id, cars.car_name, users.user_id, users.name, users.state, users.address, users.zip, users.phone, users.email 
FROM rent
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = rent.user_id 
LEFT JOIN cars ON cars.car_id = rent.car_id AND rent.user_id = users.user_id AND rent.car_id = cars.car_id
```